# .Net eCommerce application for selling subscription based publications

Tags: .net, e-commerce

I am looking for a .Net based e-commerce platform that would allow photographer or image publisher to sell the "licence" to download a limited number of items for a limited time. This would be in addition to allowing users to purchase a single image for a one time fee.

Is there an application that does that (or something close to that) out of the box?
if not, which .Net e-commerce platform would be easiest to modify for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any systems that does that out of the box. [Tea Commerce](http://www.teacommerce.dk) for Umbraco will do the trick. You will have to do a little custom programming in .NET to make the download functionality of your shop. Tea Commerce will handle the shop part, buying the limited time licenses and paying for them online. You just have to make the restrictions for downloading images based on the customers orders. With Umbraco this is quite easy.

Hope you find a system that fits your needs.

/Rune